# How can I group thumbnails inside a <div> in two rows?

Tags: jquery, css

[How can I achieve this type of layout?, I'm using Bootsrap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrYgv.png)

Comment: what you tried sofar.. post demo / relevant code?

Comment: This is not how SO works, refer help page for more info http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/H2AsM/1/ but I want to make it like in the http://nickjr.com but with same size thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13020/)**

As you mentioned, You are using Bootstrap, I just gave idea to proceed, further you can develop as you need

```
.bg {
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#ccc;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.border {
    background:#f00;
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <div class="clearfix border">
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class=" border clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class=" border clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 bg">img</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using jquery to output each image how can I modify it to have an output like you did?

Comment: 'function(data){
            var output;
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                console.log(item);
                videoTitle = item.snippet.title;
                videoThumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
                
                output = '<div  class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">';
                output += '<a href="#" class="thumbnail">';
                output += '<img src="'+videoThumb+'">';
                output += '</a></div>';
                
                //Append to results
                $('#results').append(output);
            });
        }'